# Mongo DB nested sub query - Fetch the list from sub query pass it to main query with in the same collection on same filed

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

Scenario: From “psorder” collection fetching ‘worNumber’ list along with conditions (Sub Query) and pass that list, with in the same collection and exclude those ‘worNumber’.

Query:

```
db.getCollection(‘psorder’).find({
    “personName”:{$exists:false},
    “worNumber”:{
    $nin: db.getCollection(‘psorder’).distinct(“worNumber”,{“statusId”:“new”,
    “personName”:{$exists:true},
    “personName”: { $ne: “robert” }})
    }
    }).limit(1);
```

How to achieve this in aggregation and Java code. Please guide us to sort out the below query.